# Calling findViewById() in Junit test

Tags: android, junit4

I an new to unit testing and I have a simple test method that isnt working. Here is what I have:

```
@Test
public void testLayoutAvailable() {
    View v = mMainActivity.findViewById(R.layout.main_activity);
    assertNotNull(v);
}
```

My problem is `v` is always `null`. I stepped through the code and mMainActivity is not `null` and the rest of my test methods all work fine. So I'm sure there is something simple that I'm just not aware of yet. I checked my imports and I also tried `com.packagename.R.layout.main_activity` and that also returns `null`. However the app its self works fine, so I know the layout is there and this test should pass.

Any suggestions?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was I was passing in a layout not an id to `findViewById()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you run normal JUnit tests on Android, the rest of the application isn't fully constructed.

However Android provides some helper classes which construct enough of the application such that you are able to test it. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html

I have mostly used [`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html) in the past.

Comment: Yea that is the test case I am using also. However I just found my problem. I am calling findViewById() and passing in a layout not a view. I cant believe I missed that lol. Oh well you live and learn I guess. Thanks for the assistance though.